# Compress char[] alphabet

Tags: java, arrays, char, alphabet

My best friend's girlfriend texted me and thought it would be a good idea to put some code on his cake saying happy birthday. I figured I would make an array for the alphabet, and use some serious math equations that he has to type in for it to say happy birthday and make some shapes for a simple version of his face.

Currently I have

```
class josh
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{

        char alphabet[] = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};
        char c;
       for (c = 0 ; c < 26; c++)//for statement was just a text to make sure it worked
        {
            System.out.println (alphabet[c]);
        }       
}
```

}

All i want to do is for the birthday cake's sake is to compress the a-z in the alphabet array initializer, just use something instead of typing them all out that keeps it simple. I thought of a for statement but wasn't sure how to use it like that. Any suggestions?

EDIT: she can print off a picture so I can fit more code in. if there's too much for the cake i can cut it down to something simpler.

Comment: Think she is expecting something like `System.out.println("Happy Birthday!!!");`

Comment: that's lame as hell though. he would honestly make fun of be for being so uncreative.

Comment: @HaydenHolligan problem is I think, despite all the advances that humanity has achieved so far.. Programmable cakes still eludes us..

Comment: @KarthikT well i guess my new career choice is programmable cakes. it will be accomplished.

Comment: @HaydenHolligan :) And you should learn [Perl](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PerlGolf) if you are looking to MinMax the size of the code. I still suggest aim lower if this is to be printed on a cake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use ascii numbers and loop it. for example declare a char chAlpha then initialize that with these codes:

```
char[] chAlpha = new char[26];
for (int i = 0; i < 26; ++i) {
   char[i] = (char) (i + 65);
}//note that 65-131 is decimal value of the alphabet
```

and for the small/lowercase letters:

```
char[] chAlpha = new char[26];
for (int i = 0; i < 26; ++i) {
       char[i] = (char) (i + 97);
}
```

Comment: like the above code i'm getting an error on (char) saying invalid expression.

Comment: @HaydenHolligan, you can use `for(char ch = 'A';ch <= 'Z';ch++)`

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the alphabet like so:

```
char[] alphabet = new char[26];
for (int i = 0; i < 26; ++i) {
   char[i] = (char) (i + 65);
}
```

Comment: why is it (i+65)? i'll try it out though. also it's saying there's a syntax error on the token (char), invalid expression.

Comment: @HaydenHolligan Since the `int` representation of a `char` is in ASCII, and `A` starts at 65.

Comment: Couldn't you use `for (char i = 'A'; i <= 'Z'; i++)`? Gets rid of the cast and addition, and makes it pretty obvious what's going on.

Comment: Or atleast use `i + 'A'`

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
String s1= "day!"; 
String s2= "Hap";
String s3= "py ";
String s4= "Birth";
System.out.println(s2+s3+s4+s1);
```

Comment: I want something where he doesn't know what it says right away. Also I could input something funny and nobody will know what it says until when it's run.

Comment: ok i thought it should be written on the cake